# How to retrieve id of element that a function is called on *without* using 'this' variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, jslint

I'm trying to please JSLint's desire not to use `this` except in special cases. I have an original function, like this:

```
$.fn.extend({
    my_original_function: function ([arguments]){
        [arbitrary routine]
    }
});
```

...called like this on an ID selector:

```
$('#my_id').my_original_function([arguments]);
```

In my original version of the function, I used `this` within it to return the selected DOM element on which the function is operating. However, JSLint doesn't like it, and so I'm trying to find a way to reference `#my_id` (in this example), which the function is being called on, within the function...without using `this`!

This seems like more of an academic exercise than anything, but I'm scratching my head on how I could retrieve the id within the function without using `this`. Any ideas?

*** THE FUNCTION IN QUESTION ***

It's a toggle function for switching text links when they are clicked. Here's the original version with `this`:

```
$.fn.extend({
    toggleText: function(open, close) {
        var isClicked = false;
        var that = $(this);
        $(this).click(function () {
            if (isClicked) {
                that.text(open);
                isClicked = false;
            } else {
                that.text(close);
                isClicked = true;
            }
        });
        return $(this);
    }
});

$('#id_one').toggleText("Toggle Text 1", "Toggle Text 2");
$('#id_two').toggleText("Hello", "Goodbye");
```

Comment: JSLint is likely just wrong - don't cluge your code just because it is mistaken.  If you show us the actual code in your function that is using `this`, we could help better.

Comment: If your function is an event handler, the first argument is the event, and `event.target` can be used instead of `this`.

Comment: Depending on what information you need from `this`, can you just load that information as arguments to your `my_original_function`?

Comment: @NickZuber That is the only solution I could find, but I don't like it because you have to manually code the the name of the id into the function call. If the element id could be retrieved dynamically, that would be more efficient. (And of course, 'this' seems extremely efficient, but I'm curious to see if I can pull this off.)

Comment: @Barmar Sadly, event.target doesn't work.

Comment: @Tom What about `this` does JSLint not like exactly? Could you just create a copy of `this` and pass that it as an argument?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it in general. That's the way jQuery methods work, the element they're called on is passed as the implicit `this` argument.

Comment: @NickZuber The function is called automatically by jQuery, you don't have control over the arguments that it passes.

Comment: @NickZuber and others...I've appended the original function with 'this' to my my posting; refresh the page and see.

Comment: (In renaming some of the variables to make them more descriptive, I may have inadvertently switched my `open` and `close` variables, but you'll get the point

Comment: This is a perfectly valid use of `this`. There are cases where people introduce bugs because they misunderstand how `this` works and that is what JSLint is warning you about. But since this is valid then don't listen to JSLint on this point (note: you should still look at all the other warnings it throws out)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.extend({
    toggleText: function(open, close, that) {...

$('#id_one').toggleText("Toggle Text 1", "Toggle Text 2", $('#id_one'));
```

Comment: That's the only solution I could think of, but it has the disadvantage of requiring the coder to type out the id selector explicitly instead of having the function retrieve the id dynamically.